# Android: Flip Animation using XML for animation in android

Tags: android, animation, android-layout, viewflipper, flip

For searching on net i found that there is ViewFlipper class that gives the Flip view animation between two view/ But for that should be in the same Activity. I also know that the Flip animation is not suported for the activity change. as right now android support only 2d animation during activity change.

I want is the make the same effect for changing the activity.

So is there any similar like xml animation that gives effect as like FLip View so i provide that to my activity change and get the Such Flip effect for the Activity change.

Please provide me some xml for animation that gives the Flip type animation tht works for activity change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_from_middle,R.anim.shrink_to_middle);
```

grow_from_middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.7"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="50%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

shrink_to_middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.7"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="200" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="50%"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks blessenm for answer. Let me check it.

Comment: where should i have to write this line: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_from_middle,R.anim.shrink_to_middle);

Comment: I have paste it after start activity but it tells me to crete methos with the same name.

Comment: The above code should work if you call after startactivity. The overidePandingTransisition should be available if you are starting the activity inside an activity. Otherwise you will need to use the context or something else.

Comment: Ok. But i got that is its only aplicable for android 2.0 or above.

Comment: You also can try this link: [Use Android's scale animation to simulate a 3D flip](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-scale-animation-to-simulate-a-3d-flip/)

Comment: Works great! Thank you.