# 3d animation between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have imported the library of nineoldsandroid to do 3D animation between fragments but i don´t know how, if I use for example this in anim folder I have errors because my app is to android 2.2, somebody knows how to use the library? Thank you so much.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="0" />

<!-- Rotate. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="-180"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:duration="1" />
```

Comment: That library isn't build for 3D animations.  No native library on Android is.

Comment: Thank you, I have readen that it possible create 3D flip effect between Fragments, is there other possibility?

Comment: Well, ok. A 3D flip animation can be simulated in 2D.  May try this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570906/android-flip-animation-using-xml-for-animation-in-android