# How can I start next activity from main activity using page turn effect in android?

Tags: android

I do not use animation because it do not use fingers while going to another activity and I do not use page curl animation because it uses single activity for all pages.
I want to go from one activity to other like we turn a page in book.

Comment: this page curl is used on single activity. but i want to go from one activity to another using this effect

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_from_middle,R.anim.shrink_to_middle);
```

grow_from_middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.7"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="50%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

shrink_to_middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.7"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="200" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="50%"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

From [Android: Flip Animation using XML for animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570906/android-flip-animation-using-xml-for-animation-in-android)