# Flip transition animation between two Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, flip

I am trying to move from one Fragment to another with performing a 3D flip animation. To accomplish this, I am trying to adapt the Google tutorial [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/cardflip.html#fragment) to my context. The only thing is that the guide implement both Fragments in an `Activity` while I implement the Fragments separately in two files without relying on `Activity`.

The issue I am encountering is the following runtime exception whenever I try to animate the transition:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
```

Here is the approach I followed:

1- In `build.gradle` file, the minimum SDK supported version is 14:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

2- Under the res folder, I created a new Android resource directory `anim`:
[image]

The following is the code of the 4 xml files:

**card_flip_left_in.xml:**

```
<!-- Rotate. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="-180"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
    android:duration="1" />
```

**card_flip_left_out.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

**card_flip_right_in.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />

</set>
```

**card_flip_right_out.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

Now come the interesting part, I try to perform the transition whenever on click on the marker info window:

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        System.out.println(marker.getId());
        flipCard();
    }
```

And the **flipCard** code:

```
private void flipCard() {

        if (mShowingBack) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return;
        }
        // Flip to the back.

        mShowingBack = true;
        // Create and commit a new fragment transaction that adds the fragment for the back of
        // the card, uses custom animations, and is part of the fragment manager's back stack.

        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()

                        // Replace the default fragment animations with animator resources representing
                        // rotations when switching to the back of the card, as well as animator
                        // resources representing rotations when flipping back to the front (e.g. when
                        // the system Back button is pressed).
                .setCustomAnimations(
                        R.anim.card_flip_right_in , R.anim.card_flip_right_out,
                        R.anim.card_flip_left_in, R.anim.card_flip_left_out
                )

                        // Replace any fragments currently in the container view with a fragment
                        // representing the next page (indicated by the just-incremented currentPage
                        // variable).
                .replace(R.id.audio_playback, new AudioPlayback())

                        // Add this transaction to the back stack, allowing users to press Back
                        // to get to the front of the card.
                .addToBackStack(null)

                        // Commit the transaction.
                .commit();
}
```

**One of the attempts I tried:**

I tried to move all the card animation xml files to an `animator` resource directory instead of an `anim` directory. But then whenever I change the path in the transition code to the following:

```
.setCustomAnimations(
                        R.animator.card_flip_right_in , R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                        R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out
                )
```

I got the statements above underlined in red with an error `Expected resource of type anim`. So this is to confirm this attempt doesn't seems to fix the issue.

So basically, how is the flip animation should be done? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the compatibility library which means that your resources should be in a folder called res/anim rather than res/animator and use the older syntax.

The syntax you are using is described under Property Animation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property). You should be using the syntax described under View Animation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View)

Creating slide, fade, translate or scale transitions with this syntax is not difficult but rotation is only about the X and / or Y axes and I have yet to see a successful implementation of a flip transition. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570906/android-flip-animation-using-xml-for-animation-in-android?rq=1) for one attempt.